# Target IE7 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, browser-detection

I am trying to target IE7 with an if statement in a jQuery function. My code to this specific bit is:

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substring(0) == "7") {
    //Do something
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the "right" way to do something? If not, just test you code and see if it works?

Comment: I think `parseInt($.browser.version) == 7` would be prettier.

Comment: I have tested it. The part that is not working is the if(target IE7) the else part of the function executes perfectly

Comment: Try alerting `$.browser.version` to see what it gets you.

Comment: @Karim79 I have changed my code to match your code and the if statement now works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @mtwallet: Instead of targeting a specific browser, consider detecting features instead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try:

```
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 7) {
    //Do something
}
```

And as @Andrew Whitaker comments, instead of targeting a specific browser, consider detecting features instead.

Comment: Agreed with that statement. Even the jquery apis says the following: "We recommend against using this property, please try to use feature detection instead." (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: @Tjirp, I don't think there is a way to detect the 'feature' for "IE7 draws scrollbars inside content window on overflow, IE8 draws them outside".

Comment: Nice script, upvote. However, what if I wanted to target IE7 and IE8? I tested with `if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 7,8)` and it works. However, my JSLint tells me there's an error. I'm not a JavaScript guru so I don't understand what the error means. My idea is to DYR so I don't have to repeat the same function for two different browsers. Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: `$.browser` is now removed from jQuery >= 1.9, so this no longer works.